# How to Convert Pandas Dataframe to Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have below dataframe.

```
**Col1**    **Col2**
ABC           S1
ABC           S2
BCD           S3
FJK           S5
XYZ           S7
XYZ           S8
```

I need output in the below format.

`data = {'ABC': '[S1,S2]', 'BCD': '[S3]', 'FJK': '[S5]', 'XYZ': '[S7,S8]'}`

Can anyone please help me how to achieve above output, it will be great !

Comment: Aggregate and then convert to dict: `df.groupby('Col1').Col2.agg(list).to_dict()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned commnent aggregate `list` and then convert to dictionary:

```
d = df.groupby('Col1').Col2.agg(list).to_dict()
print (d)
{'ABC': ['S1', 'S2'], 'BCD': ['S3'], 'FJK': ['S5'], 'XYZ': ['S7', 'S8']}
```

For strings use `f-strings` in lambda function:

```
d = df.groupby('Col1').Col2.agg(lambda x: f"[{','.join(x)}]").to_dict()
print (d)
{'ABC': '[S1,S2]', 'BCD': '[S3]', 'FJK': '[S5]', 'XYZ': '[S7,S8]'}
```

For json use [`Series.to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_json.html):

```
j = df.groupby('Col1').Col2.agg(list).to_json()
print (j)
{"ABC":["S1","S2"],"BCD":["S3"],"FJK":["S5"],"XYZ":["S7","S8"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a string as value, use aggregation as string:

```
data = ('['+df.groupby('Col1')['Col2'].agg(','.join)+']').to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'ABC': '[S1,S2]',
 'BCD': '[S3]',
 'FJK': '[S5]',
 'XYZ': '[S7,S8]'}
```